# Python escaping re.split treat backslash+symbol as another symbol

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I have an input string which somehow remind the html code, but tags using the square brackets instead of angular.

The input string is:
`str = r'Lorem ipsum [dolor] sit amet'`
I process it with re.split using pattern
`ptr = r'\[.*?\]'`
to detect the tags. The result is a list
`list = [r'Lorem ipsum ', r'[dolor]', r' sit amet']`
The problem is that the two-symbol sequence `\[` should mean `[` symbol, not starting a tag.

`re.split(r'\[.*?\]', r'Lorem \[ipsum\] \\[dolor] sit amet')`
gives
`[r'Lorem \', r'[ipsum\]', r' \\', r'[dolor]', r' sit amet']`
while I want to get
`[r'Lorem ipsum \[dolor\] \\', r'[dolor]', r' sit amet']`

So what I want is to understand is how to say to re.split that two-symbol sequence `\x` is and escape sequence and should be treated asa single symbol?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of putting `r` in front of a string is to treat it as a raw string -> Python will treat backslashes as literal characters. You should just use normal strings.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?:[^][\\]|\\.)+|\[[^][]*]', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEIC87/1) and its graph:

[image]

**In brief**:

- `(?:[^][\\]|\\.)+` - one or more sequences of any char but `]`, `[` and `\` or any char (but a line break char if you do not specify `re.DOTALL`flag) escaped with a backslash
- `|` - or
- `\[[^][]*]` - a `[`, then any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/3QyxaM):

```
import re
rx = r"(?:[^][\\]|\\.)+|\[[^][]*]"
s = r"Lorem \[ipsum\] \\[dolor] sit amet"
results = re.findall(r'(?:[^][\\]|\\.)+|\[[^][]*]', s)
for result in results:
    print("'{}'".format(result))
```

Output:

```
'Lorem \[ipsum\] \\'
'[dolor]'
' sit amet'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we might want to split our string to three parts, for that we can just use three capturing groups and collect what we wish to output, maybe similar to:

```
(.+?\\\\)(\[.+\])(.+)
```

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.+?\\\\)(\[.+\])(.+)"

test_str = "Lorem \\[ipsum\\] \\\\[dolor] sit amet"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qoSkpt/1)

```js
const regex = /(.+?\\\\)(\[.+\])(.+)/gm;
const str = `Lorem \\[ipsum\\] \\\\[dolor] sit amet`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. Thank to them I found the solution I need.

To display the problem, let substitute the tags `[atag]` with `<atag>`. BUT, the sequence `\[` should remain untouched, since it's "escaped". The backslash should be also "escaped", i.e. `\\` remain untouched so that `\\[` transforms into `\\<`. But, again, `\\\[` remains `\\\[`. An so on.

The following code

```
import re

test_str = r"Lorem \[ipsum\] dolor [sit\]amet], consetetur [sadipscing\\] elitr, \\[sed] diam [nonumy]"

regex = r"(?P<prefix>[^\\](\\\\)*)\[(?P<expression>.*?[^\\](\\\\)*)\]"
subst = r"\g<prefix><\g<expression>>"

print (re.sub(regex, subst, test_str))
```

results in

```
Lorem \[ipsum\] dolor <sit\]amet>, consetetur <sadipscing\\> elitr, \\<sed> diam <nonumy>
```

As wished.

Hope this will help someone.